# Gatsby Error persisting state: function could not be cloned

Tags: node.js, webpack, runtime-error, gatsby, build-error

Recently I have migrated from Gatsby V2 to V4, using the [official docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/) since that Iam facing this warning and It goes like this,

```
warn Error persisting state: function createFolder(folderData) {
    return client.mutate({
      mutation: mutations.createFo...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
```

Iam using node version : 14.15.4
and npm version : 6.14.10

Is anybody faced this error before or suggest any way to resolve this.

Comment: Well, the docs said literally from v2 to v3. Have you tried the project in the v3 or you directly go from v2 to v4?

Comment: @FerranBuireu  I have used command which was mentioned in the docs
`{
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^3.0.0"
  }
}`
It updates the version to V3 successfully but,while updating the gatsby-plugins
using this command 

`npm install gatsby-plugin-sharp@latest`

Its not adaptable to V3

So, I used this command to update them all together to the latest version,

`npm install gatsby@latest`

Comment: So the problem is from v2 to v3, not to v4. Have you tried updating your npm version up to version 7 to run the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest updating your npm version up to version 7 in order to run:

```
npm install gatsby@latest --legacy-peer-deps
```

As well:

```
npm outdated
```

To compare your wanted version to the latest.

Keep in mind that if some dependency is not updated to any accordingly working version, your project may not be able to run. However, in the case of the `gatsby-plugin-sharp`, being an official maintained plugin I guess it will be compatible with v3 (they just shipped the v4 recently so...).

Prior to that suggestions, I'd also recommend cleaning cache in each process as well reinstalling your dependencies (or the locked ones) removing your node_modules, your `package-lock.json`, etc if needed.

Share you configuration details (`gatsby-config.js`) to see if there's something that needs to be refactored in the version 3.

Comment: I am using npm version below 7 only, And everything else is working fine , The Build also success. Only thing remaining is the warning I mentioned above, so I am trying to find the solution for that.

Comment: As I said, try sharing your `gatsby-config.js` to see if there's a clue there from where the issue can come from. If the site works as expected a warning (besides it's not ideal) it will never break your compilation nor your site.